# C# Repeater displaying single listing 12 times

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater I'm using to display a sidebar nav type system on my page. It loads some data from a db for the display of the links. It should be showing a single listing in this case, however it shows the same listing a total of 13 times.

My code:

```
        private void Load_Locations()   //Loads a list of locations.
    {
        var query = from q in CurrentContext.LOC
                    join w in CurrentContext.int on q.key equals w.L_key
                    select new
                    {
                        Location = q.Location
                    };
        rpt_locations.DataSource = query;
        rpt_locations.DataBind();
    }
```

^to pull the data from the database, works perfectly as I use the same snippet for other things.

```
    <div class="Side_Menu" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_locations" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_locations_ItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_location" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Location") %>' Font-Underline="False" OnClick="btn_location_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_location" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Location") %>' Font-Underline="False" OnClick="btn_location_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

^Asp coding for the repeater.

Havn't expericned this issue before, pretty lost on how it's happening.

Comment: What is in `rpt_locations_ItemCommand` and can you visually confirm that the LINQ `join` isn't causing 13 duplicate Location values?

Comment: use `Distinct`, if you really can't suppress duplicates from your `LINQ` query

Comment: the rpt_locations_ItemCommand is the onclick that handles the clicks.

I'll give Distinct a shot